# Including Jquery or similar files, should it be conditional?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Simple and fast question:

I need the jquery library for a site, so I access it in my header.php file as such:

```
<head>
    <!-- include jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

Now my question is should I also be putting some other php scripting in there to make sure it is only included when I need it for a given page? My gut tells me I am absolutely right to only load the jquery files when I need them, yet I swear I always see things like this loaded without thought to if they are actually needed for the given situation. So perhaps there is no harm in always having it there.

So should it be like this?? Pseudo code:

```
<head>
        <?php 
           //set jquery variable to true or false in configure.php file based on situation
           if($jquery){
           //include the jquery script!!
           }
            else{
           //jquery??? we don't need that here
           } 
        ?>


 </head>
```

Comment: In my opinion it doesnt matter either way. Scripts, especially if you use hosted versions (which jQuery provides several of), can get cached so the worry about loading time is really not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally better to load only what you need for a page, but if you do include jQuery everywhere, make sure:

1) It's minified (to reduce overhead).

2) You serve from a CDN (e.g. [Google's](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery)). The likelihood of the user having a cached version (and thus a faster page load) will be much higher. See:

http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Comment: again, appreciate the tip off to letting google host the jquery

Answer (score 0):

It's not that big a deal.

Keep in mind that (most) people's browsers will cache files, for at least a certain duration of time. If say your homepage doesn't require jQuery, but the about page does, people with slower internet connections will be suffering a longer page load duration on your about page.

Even so, you should absolutely try to use minified versions of jQuery to reduce the amount of data you have to serve, and your users have to download. Even better is to use a CDN like Google's, as they're optimised for distribution to users, and also because with it in use widely, people are more likely to have it already cached on their system. [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) has a nice way to include jQuery from the Google CDN, and use the copy on your server as a fallback:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="path/to/jquery-1.5.1.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

The issue of longer page loads can also be somewhat offset by having your jQuery include tag before the `</body>` tag, as scripts and stylesheets block page load until they're fully downloaded (for the majority of browsers). The only issue with doing that is that anything that depends on jQuery for site interaction of course won't respond immediately.

Given, if you absolutely want to conditionally include jQuery, that code snippet you provided should work fine.